# Google Drive V3 APi: how to get many files by Id

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using the Google.Apis.Drive.v3,

For my application I am storing the GoogleIds of files (because the names might change). I want to fetch the meta data for the files to get the names, however there doesnt be a clear way to get multiple files by Id.

I can use `DriveService.Files.Get("A_GOOGLE_FILE_ID")` which will ge me one file by Id

I can use (the following bellow) to query files, although I can search by folderId, I cant search by fileId,

```
   FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
   listRequest.PageSize = 500;
   listRequest.Fields = "*";


   var idQueryClause = string.Join(" or ", ids.Select(id => $" '{id}' in parents"));
   listRequest.Q = $" trashed=false and application/vnd.google-apps.folder and ({idQueryClause})";

   var result = await listRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

I suppose what im looking for is something like

```
    DriveService.Files.Get(IEnumerable<string> folderIds)
```

or some kind of query syntax that enables finding by Ids

```
 listRequest.Q = " id in ('aaaaa','bbbb', 'ccccc')";
```

I have been throught the documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files and couldnt see anything

Comment: IIRC drive api v3 doesn't have that feature. You would have to write your own multithreaded/iterative function to do so

Answer (score 0):

for the moment I have done this

```cs
var tasks = new List<Task<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File>>();
foreach(var id in ids)
{
    var thing = service.Files.Get(id);
    var task = thing.ExecuteAsync();
    tasks.Add(task);
}

var files = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Although I'm sure google dont appreciate being hit multiple times when it could be done at once

Comment: how many requests were you able to execute at once before hitting rate limits, if you happen to know?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of files using a query and then filter that list comparing each fileID with your folderIds array:

```
FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
listRequest.PageSize = 500;
listRequest.Fields = "*";
//Search for untrashed folders
listRequest.Q = $" trashed=false and application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

// List files 
IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute().Files;
if (files != null && files.Count > 0) {
    foreach (var file in files) {
        foreach (var fileID in folderIds) {
            if (file.Id == fileID) {
            var thing = file;
            //Do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In "Do something" you can implement the code to store all the files, with the given IDs, in a single array to work with it outside the loops.

Comment: Yes this would definately work, however I wanted to benefit from the speed of selecting the files by Id, for the soloution above, I would have to potentially select all folders on the drive just to filter all but a few of the results. However thanks for providing an alternative

Comment: As there's no operator to filter by ID, the only way to do that would be using a batch with several get requests (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch), that would speed up the process as you have it now but it still would spend the same amount of Google quota. The code I provided is the most efficient quota-wise.